# Laravel 5.3 creating multi dimention array from DB results

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

**Reuqirment**

My DB has a table named *`categories`* and also a table named *`products`* where products table has a row named ***`category_id`* which make the relationship with *`categories`* table**. So I wants to show random 7 categories from my *categories* table and also I needs to show 6 products from each category too.

**Framework**

Laravel 5.3

**What I have done**

- To fetch 8 random categories

  This code work as I wants so no issue with this code segment

  ```
   $masterCategoryList = Category::where('parent_id', 0)
                                    ->where('id', '!=',0)
                                    ->inRandomOrder()
                                    ->take(8)
                                    ->get();
  ```
- Fetch 6 random products for each selected random Master Category List id `$masterCategoryList`
  So what I have done is

  ```
  $productsMatcheToMasterCategory = []; 

           for($a = 0; $a<8; $a++){

     $productsMatcheToMasterCategory =
                             Product::where('category_id',$masterCategoryList[$a]['id'])    
                             ->inRandomOrder()
                             ->take(6)
                             ->get();    
   }
  ```

But this only output 6 products which related one category when I use  dd`($productsMatcheToMasterCategory)`after the loop.Like below

```
 Category 01

       - Product 01

       - Product 02
```

My expected out put is something like below

```
Category 01
           - Product 01
           - Product 02
Category 02
           - Product 01
           - Product 02
```

Could anyone please tell me why does this happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way you are doing it, you are overriding the value you previously assigned to the variable. To avoid that, add an empty pair of brackets to the variable to indicate that you assign each result of each query in the loop to a new element in the array.

```php
$masterCategoryList = Category::where('parent_id', 0)
                                ->where('id', '!=',0)
                                ->inRandomOrder()
                                ->take(8)
                                ->get();

$productsMatcheToMasterCategory = []; 

for($a = 0; $a < 8; $a ++) {
    // here note the $productsMatcheToMasterCategory [] = ...
    $productsMatcheToMasterCategory [] = Product::where('category_id',$masterCategoryList[$a]['id'])    
                                                ->inRandomOrder()
                                                ->take(6)
                                                ->get();    
}
```

but in that way you have 9 queries, 1 to get the eight categories and 8 to get the products for each category.

Another approach I can think of is by defining the relationships in the models:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
    }
}



class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

and getting the related products by the method `with()` [constraining the eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads), wich results in just one query:

```php
$collection = Category::where('parent_id', 0)
            ->where('id', '!=',0)
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->take(8)
            ->with([
                'products' => function($query) {
                    $query->inRandomOrder()
                          ->take(6);
                },
            ])
            ->get();
$array = $collection->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for this well explained answer

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are just replacing the value inside the array. It is just creating the array with index 0.

```
$productsMatcheToMasterCategory = []; 
for($a = 0; $a<8; $a++){
$output =
Product::where('category_id',$masterCategoryList[$a]['id'])    
         ->inRandomOrder()
         ->take(6)
         ->get();    
array_push($productsMatcheToMasterCategory, $output)
}
```

Comment: please rename function arry to array. Thanks